# Is there a traditional name for the "eigenspace" function?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, terminology

Let $A$ denote a field, $X$ denote an $A$-vector spaces, and suppose $\varphi : X \rightarrow X$ is a linear transformation. Is there a traditional name for the corresponding "eigenspace" function? By which I mean the unique function $\varphi' : A \rightarrow \mathrm{Sub}(X)$ defined as follows. $$\varphi'(\lambda) = \{x \in X \mid \varphi x = \lambda x\}$$

I am also interested in traditional notation for this function.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @lhf, its very hard to learn more about a function if you do not know its name.

Comment: The eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda \in A$ is sometimes written $X_\lambda$; the transformation $\varphi$ is usually clear from the context. That's as much notation as I know of.

Comment: @lhf, thanks. $\;\!$

Comment: In the context of the spectral theorem for a compact self-adjoint operators on Hilbert spaces, if you're happy to identify a closed subspace with the orthogonal projection onto that subspace, then the map you're looking at is well-known as a *projection-valued measure*. Of course, the spectral theorem extends to non-compact operators as well, but then things become considerably more subtle.